# Singleton Object in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, singleton

As we know that a singleton object can be instantiated only once and we use singletons in objective C to have a global access to shared resources. We also know that singletons are instantiated using the following method.

```
    + (instancetype)sharedManager
{
    static PhotoManager *sharedPhotoManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedPhotoManager = [[[self class] alloc] init];
        sharedPhotoManager->_photosArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    });
    return sharedPhotoManager;
}
```

But I can also do this -

```
PhotoManager *sharedManager = [[PhotoManager alloc] init];
```

Now this way I can also create another instance of the same singleton class then how come the class is singleton if it is having two instances.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forbid calls of `init` with such trick: 
add `- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;` definition to your singleton interface.

Instead of `[[PhotoManager alloc] init];` use `[[[self class] alloc] init];`

`PhotoManager *sharedManager = [[PhotoManager alloc] init];` won't compile.

There is my example:

```
@interface SomeSingleton : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;

@end

@implementation SomeSingleton

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static SomeSingleton *instance;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    return self;
}

@end
```

As result `SomeSingleton *s1 = [SomeSingleton sharedInstance];` works, but `SomeSingleton *s2 = [[SomeSingleton alloc] init];` leads to the compile error.

Comment: I think in class methods you can even omit the call to `class` since in the class method, `self` already refers to the class.

Comment: @LukasSpieß, you're right

Answer (score 0):

You have singleton behaviour for object only when you use `sharedManager:` class method. All other ways you instantiate object are not guaranteed to produce singleton object.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C allows you to do lots of things that may not be intended. Like calling a private method if you know the method name.

If you are obsessed to make sure your class is only used as singleton, maybe something like this would be of use:

```
static PhotoManager *sharedPhotoManager = nil;

+ (instancetype)sharedManager
{
    if (!sharedPhotoManager) {
        sharedPhotoManager = [[PhotoManager alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedPhotoManager;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    if (sharedPhotoManager) {
        // init method is allowed to return different object
        return sharedPhotoManager;
    }
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you write

```
PhotoManager *sharedManager = [[PhotoManager alloc] init];
```

you are not getting your sharedInstance, you are creating a new one. The way you should use it is

```
[PhotoManager sharedInstance];
```

instead of

```
PhotoManager *sharedManager = [[PhotoManager alloc] init];
```

When you create a singleton class you has never use alloc init, you always should use sharedInstance method to keep the same instance in your app

By the way... as [T_77](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3695849/t-77) suggest you, you should use dispatch_once instead of your implementation to create an instance.

```
 + (instancetype)sharedInstance
 {
     static dispatch_once_t once;
     static id sharedInstance;
     dispatch_once(&once, ^{
         sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
     });
     return sharedInstance;
 }
```

Comment: and I still got down vote :P

Comment: @T_77, probably because you don't answer the question, why it is called singleton if indeed it is possible to create more than one object.

Comment: you are right. I will keep it in mind. :)

Comment: @SonGoku68 Please read the question carefully. I know the method to get a shared instance. But my question is how to prevent creating another instance of same class if we can alloc init.